# Is there any consequence after Fatigued if you continue going without rest?

Tags: conditions, pathfinder-2e, rests

In Pathfinder 2e, if you miss a night's sleep you become [Fatigued](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=15), and you can get rid of this with a night's sleep.
But after this, I can't find any other consequences for missing even longer periods; can you just keep missing sleep forever and only remain "Fatigued"?

Note this is also interesting because this means you miss your daily preparations, presumably certain feats don't reset, like [Hunt Prey](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=10).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There are no levels of exhaustion

Fatigue is a singular Condition to represent all levels of being tired. There are no higher levels or penalties for extended lack of rest.

You'll notice that it is not listed in the [Groups of Conditions](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx) (Core Rulebook p619), only as its own Condition.

Comment: So, if you can put up with "Fatigued" then theoretically you never have to sleep?

Comment: I suppose, although I wouldn't expect GM's to sit by allowing it all the time (eventually people can't stay awake)

Comment: Oh yes; it's silly; but was examining it in a RAW way.